# Excel to datagridview: Not displaying numbered cells to grid c# web application

Tags: c#, excel, windows, datagridview, oledbconnection

i am developing a C# web application which need to process an excel sheet containing names of places and deposits and withdrawals which will be sorted and displayed in datagridview and later it will be saved in a microsoft access database.

I am able to retrieve officenames, sort and display the contents in datagridview

[Click to watch the output of datagrid view on the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFABH.png)

But the problem is my excel file contains both strings and numbers in its sheet.

[Excel file screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edj5r.png)

[Excel file screen shot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpqgP.png)

As you can see even though the excel file contains numbers, the datagridview on the right doesn't display excel cells with number values. Please watch the gridview on the right in the first image for the reference.

The code i am using is:

```
 using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                {
                    System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + sheetName + "]";

                    //new code to displayi contents to temp datagrid

                    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
                    System.Data.DataSet DtSet;
                    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand;
                    MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='C:\Users\acer\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SBCO consolidation Reporter\SBCO consolidation Reporter\Files\RD1.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
                    MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * From [" + sheetName + "]", MyConnection);
                    MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Net-informations.com");
                    DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
                    MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);
                    dataGridView2.DataSource = DtSet.Tables[0];
                    MyConnection.Close();



                    //new code end

                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    oda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    oda.Fill(dt);
                    con.Close();
                    //Populate DataGridView.
                    System.Data.DataTable tempDT = new System.Data.DataTable();
                    tempDT = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "F2");
                    foreach (DataRow row in tempDT.AsEnumerable().Take(7).ToList())
                    {
                        row.Delete();
                    }


                    int count = tempDT.Rows.Count;
                    tempDT.Rows[count - 1].Delete();
                    tempDT.Rows[count - 2].Delete();
                    tempDT.Rows[count - 4].Delete();
                    DataView dv = tempDT.DefaultView;
                    dv.Sort = "F2 asc";
                    System.Data.DataTable sortedDT = dv.ToTable();
                    sortedDT.Columns[0].ColumnName = "Office Name";
                    //sortedDT.Columns[1].ColumnName = "Finacle Dep";
                    sortedDT.Columns.Add("Profit Center Code", typeof(System.Int32));
                    sortedDT.Columns.Add("Finacle Dep", typeof(System.Int32));
                    sortedDT.Columns.Add("Finacle Withdrawal", typeof(System.Int32));
                    tempDT.AcceptChanges();
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = sortedDT;
                    dataGridView1.Columns["Office Name"].ReadOnly = true;


                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

So where am i doing it wrong. Please help!

Comment: To be honest hard to answer that as the columns in your dataview dont match any from the spreadsheet, nor do the names in the first column

Comment: @BugFinder I had uploaded a sample first page of the excel sheet previously. Now i have uploaded the full content screenshot

Comment: Well, the column names still dont match up, but you will need to look and debug because with the info supplied its hard to give you a solid reason

Comment: Ya thats why i used Default column names i.e.,  F2,F3 etc i can able to retrieve column F2 successfully but the problem appears when i try to change the column. To test the same, i have created datagridview2 to retrieve all the column names and data extracted in which i have found numbers are not displaying. You can watch that in the first screenshot

Comment: F2 has no data in it... so.. perhaps thats why

Comment: Did you notice the weird column layout in the excel sheet? many tiny or hidden ones

Comment: Yeah that is a default layout. I dont have to worry about that. All i want is to retrieve data from it. By the way from the code you can see i have deleted the null values and first 4 or 5 rows according to my need and sorted out. everything from column F2. That doesnt work with F5 which has deposit number values.